# Can I get a visa on arrival at Bahrain with a new GCC Residence Permit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visas-on-arrival, bahrain, gcc

I just received my Residence Permit for Kuwait. I am planning a visit for two days to Bahrain and have already booked a round trip ticket.

Will the permit be acceptable for a visa on arrival at Bahrain?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 2):

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=BH&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=IS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines, states:

> Passengers with a **resident permit** issued by **Kuwait**, Oman,
>     Qatar, Saudi Arabia and United Arab Emirates **can obtain a visa on arrival** for a maximum stay of 1 month if:
>
> - the residence permit is at least 3 months old,and valid
>     for at least another 3 months when entering Bahrain and
> - having a re-entry visa issued by the country of residency
>     and
> - having a hotel reservation confirmation and
>     having a return/onward ticket for next destination andsufficient funds to cover their stay.

**However**, you can also apply for an [electronic entry permit](https://www.evisa.gov.bh/VISA/visaInput), with which you will get through immigration quicker, without having to send your passport to an embassy. As such, I highly recommend this option.

Comment: So they will not give me visa because my RP is new as less than a month? I met all the requirements but only that is my concern. thanks!

Comment: @Sassygirl Correct; however, if you apply for an electronic entry permit, your passport must only be valid for your whole stay in Bahrain, and you do not even need to show your residence permit at the border